# No output in the parent process without fflush(stdout)

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, fflush

I'm trying to understand what is behind this behaviour in my parent process.

Basically, I create a child process and connect its stdout to my pipe. The parent process continuously reads from the pipe and does some stuff.

I noticed that when inserting the while loop in the parent the stdout seems to be lost, nothing appears on the terminal etc I thought that the output of stdout would somehow go to the pipe (maybe an issue with dup2) but that doesn't seem to be the issue. If I don't continuously `fflush(stdout)` in the parent process, whatever I'm trying to get to the terminal just won't show. Without a while loop in the parent it works fine, but I'm really not sure why it's happening or if the rest of my implementation is problematic somehow.

Nothing past the read system call seems to be going to the stdout in the parent process. Assuming the output of inotifywait in the pipe is small enough ( 30 > bytes ), what exactly is wrong with this program?

What I expect to happen is the stdout of inotifywait to go to the pipe, then for the parent to read the message, run strtok and print the file name (which only appears in stdout when I fflush)

Running the program with inotify installed and creating any file in the current directory of the program should be enough. Removing the while loop does print the created file's name (as expected).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(void) {
  char b[100];
  int pipefd;
  if (mkfifo("fifo", 0666) == -1) {
    if (errno != EEXIST) {
      perror("mkfifo");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((pipefd = open("fifo", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
    perror("open pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (pid == 0) {
    dup2(pipefd, 1);
    const char* dir = ".";
    const char* args[] = {"inotifywait", dir,  "-m",       "-e",
                          "create",      "-e", "moved_to", NULL};
    execvp("inotifywait", (char**)args);
    perror("inotifywait");
  } else {
    while (1) {
      fflush(stdout);  // the output only appears in stdout with this here
      if (read(pipefd, b, 30) < 0) {
        perror("problem @ read");
        exit(1);
      }
      char filename[30];
      printf("anything");
      sscanf(b, "./ CREATE %s", filename);
      printf("%s", filename);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to create a filesystem-resident fifo for the purpose?  For a transient communication channel between parent and child processes, it would be more conventional to use `pipe()`.

Comment: I have tried with unnamed pipes as well but it's the same behaviour.

Comment: Why do you expect *any* output to (the parent's) stdout?  Why do you claim that you get any?  In the program presented, the child writes its output to the fifo, and the parent reads and ignores it.  Voila, no output.  Did you mean to ask about a different program?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: My main problem is, inside of the `while(1)` loop I have a `printf` that after strtok prints out the final file name. What I expect to happen is the stdout of inotifywait to go to the pipe, then for the parent to read the message, run strtok and print the file name (which only appears in stdout when I fflush)

Comment: Your main problem *here* is that you have presented a program that is not representative of the issue you want to solve.  I hope you can see how that undermines our ability to help you.  Our standard expectation is that questions seeking debugging help present a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please make clear *what* output does not appear without `fflush`. I don't get any output with a modified version of your program. Please create a [mre], i.e. a program we can compile and run without warnings or errors and everything needed to reproduce the problem. If the problem is not related to running `inotifywait`, replace this with other code, e.g. a script that produces similar output. Note that the output of `inotifywait` might get delayed because `stdout` is connected to a pipe which will normally use buffering.

Comment: @pol Please [edit] your question to add information or clarification, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: I've updated the question, hope it's enough information now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @pol: Did you actually test whether the posted code reproduces the problem, or do you only believe that it does, because you tested similar code? I am asking because I have experienced the latter several times with other people, and it turned out afterwards that the posted code did not reproduce the issue.

Comment: It does for me. Removing the fflush just wont send anything in the stdout from the parent process.

Comment: It was important that you showed us what was behind the comment `//extract filename using string manipulation and print it` in [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72044300/1) of the question. Without your edit in which you showed what code was behind that comment, we had no way of knowing that you were using `printf` instead of `write`, and your question would have been unanswerable. This demonstrates why always providing a [mre] is important.

Answer (score 2):

The streams used by the C standard library are designed in such a way that they are normally buffered (except for the standard error stream `stderr`).

The standard output stream is normally line buffered, unless the output device is not an interactive device, in which case it is normally fully buffered. Therefore, in your case, it is probably line buffered.

This means that the buffer will only be flushed

1. when it is full,
2. when an `\n` character is encountered,
3. when the stream is closed (e.g. during normal program termination),
4. when reading input from an unbuffered or line-buffered stream (in certain situations), or
5. when you explicitly call `fflush`.

This explains why you are not seeing the output, because none of the above are happening in your infinite loop (when you don't call `fflush`). Although you are reading input, you are not doing this from a C standard library `FILE *` stream. Instead, you are bypassing the C runtime library (e.g. glibc) by using the `read` system call directly (i.e. you are using a file descriptor instead of a stream).

The simplest solution to your problem would probably be to replace the line

```
printf("%s", filename);
```

with:

```
printf("%s\n", filename);
```

If `stdout` is line-buffered (which should be the case if it is connected to a terminal), then the input should automatically be flushed after every line and an explicit call to `fflush` should no longer be necessary.